# cp command follows symbolic link at destination and clobbers link target instead of overwriting link

Tags: symlink, cp

I have a symbolic link, `sd/common.py -> actual_file`, and I want to replace the link with a generated file.

However, whenever I do

```bash
cp /tmp/Star_Wrangler/common.py sd/common.py
```

... it copies from `/tmp/Star_Wrangler/common.py` and overwrites the `actual_file` instead of just replacing the symbolic link as I intend. Every time I forget to delete the symbolic link before copying, this keeps happening.

Is there an option to get the behaviour I expect? I look at the manuals, but they all talk about symbolic links at the source, not at the target.

Comment: This, coincidentally, is also the reason why build scripts test exactly how the locally installed version of some executable behaves in specific circumstances.

Comment: @MechMK1 Another reason why everytime I've started a script in bash, I end up regretting it and switching to Python. It just works and it works across platforms and any utility I need, I can call with subprocess

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This depends on what Unix you are using.

On some BSD systems (OpenBSD, FreeBSD), you will find that `cp -f` will unlink (remove) the symbolic link and replace it with the source.

Using GNU `cp`, this would not have the same effect, and you would need to use the long option `--remove-destination` instead.

On macOS, use `cp -c` to, as the manual says, "copy files using `clonefile(2)`".

On NetBSD, use `cp -a` ("archive mode", the same as `cp -RpP` on that system).  This  doesn't work on GNU, macOS, OpenBSD, or FreeBSD, even though all of these systems have the same or similar `-a` option for `cp` (on GNU systems, it's the same as `-dR --preserve`).

You already mention this yourself: Removing the link before copying the file will solve the issue.  The `rm` utility removes the link rather than the file referenced by the link.  This is also the most portable way to replace a symbolic link with a regular file.

If you are writing a script, then I suggest that you use `rm` followed by `cp`.

If you are working interactively and keep forgetting to do this, then it's also likely that you forget to use a specific option with `cp` for these situations.

Answer (score 3):

Symlinks have very confusing behavior, not just with `cp`, but also `chmod`, `chown` and the builtin `test` (or its `[ .. ]` alias) for example.

**Remove the symlink first** (`rm -f sd/common.py`), then `cp`.

Sure, the various `cp`'s on various systems have various options to do this, but it's very easy to get wrong-footed.

Another thing you can do is avoid `cp` and aim for a symlink result. `ln -sf SOURCE DESTINATION` (with both args being absolute paths) works on all POSIX systems and does not create any further confusions. `-f` removes any existing `DESTINATION` file / symlink (but not dir, alas). You can combine this with `realpath` to avoid the relative / absolute path problem:

```
ln -sf "$(realpath "$SOURCE")" "$(realpath "$DESTINATION")"
```